# Retaining quotes while dumping python dictionary into a yaml file

Tags: python, yaml

I have the following string:
'"I Do Not Feel Sad","Intermediate Level Between I Do Not Feel Sad And I Feel Sad","I Feel Sad","Intermediate Level Between I Feel Sad And I Am Sad All The Time And I Can\'t Snap Out Of It","I Am Sad All The Time And I Can\'t Snap Out Of It","Intermediate Level Between I Am Sad All The Time And I Can\'t Snap Out Of It And I Am So Sad And Unhappy That I Can\'t Stand It","I Am So Sad And Unhappy That I Can\'t Stand It"'

Which is the result of a read_csv call. It is loaded into a python dictionary as the key: value pair:

{enums: '"I Do Not Feel Sad","Intermediate Level Between I Do Not Feel Sad And I Feel Sad","I Feel Sad","Intermediate Level Between I Feel Sad And I Am Sad All The Time And I Can\'t Snap Out Of It","I Am Sad All The Time And I Can\'t Snap Out Of It","Intermediate Level Between I Am Sad All The Time And I Can\'t Snap Out Of It And I Am So Sad And Unhappy That I Can\'t Stand It","I Am So Sad And Unhappy That I Can\'t Stand It"'}

When I dump this dictionary to a yaml file I need the output to be of the form:

So to this, I pass the string into the function

```
def enum2list(enums):
    stripped = []
    splitenums = enums.split('"')
    enumpro = list(filter(lambda x: x != ' ' and x != ',' and x != '', splitenums))
    S = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString
    strns = [S(e) for e in enumpro]
    return newst
```

This successfully splits up the string and then adds the quotes, but when I 
dump it using

```
yaml= YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = False
yaml.indent(offset = 2, sequence = 4, mapping = 2)
fs = open(f'./{n}.yaml', 'w')
yaml.dump(dictlist[0], fs)
fs.close()
```

It outputs with the backslashes retained.

Desired:

```
enums: 
  - "I Do Not Feel Sad"
  - "Intermediate Level Between I Do Not Feel Sad And I Feel Sad"
  - "I Feel Sad"
  - "Intermediate Level Between I Feel Sad And I Am Sad All The Time And I         Can't Snap Out Of It"
  - "I Am Sad All The Time And I Can't Snap Out Of It"
  - "Intermediate Level Between I Am Sad All The Time And I Can't Snap Out    Of It And I Am So Sad And Unhappy That I Can't Stand It"
  - "I Am So Sad And Unhappy That I Can't Stand It"
```

Actual:

```
enums:
  - "I Do Not Feel Sad"
  - "Intermediate Level Between I Do Not Feel Sad And I Feel Sad"
  - "I Feel Sad"
  - "Intermediate Level Between I Feel Sad And I Am Sad All The Time   And I Can't\
        \ Snap Out Of It"
   - "I Am Sad All The Time And I Can't Snap Out Of It"
      - "Intermediate Level Between I Am Sad All The Time And I Can't     Snap Out Of\
        \ It And I Am So Sad And Unhappy That I Can't Stand It"
   - "I Am So Sad And Unhappy That I Can't Stand It"
```

Comment: You might want to include the import, and maybe the pip install command. It would help if the sample data were in a code block like data = """stuff""""

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting `enum` in `enum2list` on `,` instead of `"`?

Comment: I chose " because there are , within the strings I need to maintain

Comment: I see.  Maybe then splitting on `","`?

Comment: How is this different than your original suggestion?

Comment: The original  was `,` and this one is `","`

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately that still results in the same thing. I don't know if its the splitting that is the problem or the reintroduction of the quotes. However, I do need the quotes.